# Getting Linksys N600 to work with ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit)

Tags: wireless, 13.04, drivers, usb

I decided to switch my old computer from windows to Ubuntu for my son to use and I can't get the Linksys N600 wireless adapter to work.
If I type lsusb I get the following indicating that its able to recognize the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13b1:003a Linksys AE2500 802.11abgn Wireless Adapter [Broadcom BCM43236]
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 15d9:0a4d Trust International B.V. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1d57:32da Xenta 2.4GHz Receiver (Keyboard and Mouse)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

however, when I type iwconfig I get the following:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Any help is much appreciated,
thanks!

Comment: http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Linksys_AE2500

Comment: Possibly useful: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers